# Definition conflicts with previous value - also, when is override deleted?

Tags: swift, uitableview

So I am attempting to make a tableview out of an array of cloudkit downloaded items.  However, I'm having this simple little "definition conflicts with pervious value" error.  This error occurs for the cellForRowAtIndexPath function - which supposedly conflicts with the numberOfRowsInSection function.  I have attempted moving/deleting brackets of the latter function and by placing a question mark/optional at the end... "-> UITableViewCell?" to no avail.  Where could the error be coming from?

Also, as it stands, xcode deleted the override portion of each tableview function.  Why does it sometimes stay and when is it deleted?

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit
class DiningTable: UITableViewController {
 var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

func getRecords()
    {
        categories = []

        let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

       let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "DiningTypes", predicate: predicate)

        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        queryOperation.desiredKeys  = ["Name", "Address", "Picture"]
        queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord) -> Void in
            let categoryRecord = record
            self.categories.append(categoryRecord)
    }
        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
        return self.categories.count
    }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining") as! DiningTableCell
        let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.RestaurantName?.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String


       let img = restaurant.objectForKey("Picture") as! CKAsset

        cell.RestaurantPhoto.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path!)


        return cell
    }
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {    
        if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RestaurantTable {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destViewController.indexpath1 = indexPath  
        }
    }
    }
func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the code and the error message as actual text, not only as screenshot.

Comment: Updated.  When is a screenshot acceptable and when is code preferred?

Comment: Screenshots of code are pretty much never a good idea, since the first thing anybody who wants to answer will want to do is copy and paste your code into Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's your code or could you have accidentally removed some lines?

Because, as it stands, your table view functions are actually embedded in your viewDidLoad function... They need to be object level functions.

Note the indentation level of your code when you have Xcode indent the code for you (Right-click on the screen and select Structure->Re-indent.

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class DiningTable: UITableViewController {
    var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    } // <---  you are missing this close brace here.

    func getRecords()
    {
        categories = []

        let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "DiningTypes", predicate: predicate)

        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        queryOperation.desiredKeys  = ["Name", "Address", "Picture"]
        queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord) -> Void in
            let categoryRecord = record
            self.categories.append(categoryRecord)
        }
        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
        return self.categories.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining") as! DiningTableCell
        let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.RestaurantName?.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String


        let img = restaurant.objectForKey("Picture") as! CKAsset

        cell.RestaurantPhoto.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path!)


        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
            if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RestaurantTable {
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                destViewController.indexpath1 = indexPath
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your entire class definition is nested inside your

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```

function. Put a closing brace in after the call to super.viewDidLoad()